How should I retrieve the newly-created record made by a TMyQuery?
I'm making an INSERT INTO with TMyQuery, but I'm not sure how to get the inserted data back (ie the primary key). I'm reading in the documentation that I should use SQLInsert, but it's just a list of strings ? How do I get the data from that ?
I've tried simply accessing a field after calling Execute() with FieldByName() but the field doesn't exist.
Edit : I'm using MySQL 8. I thought MyDAC components were MySQL-specific (given the My in the name).

INSERT adds the row. It does not return a resultset, so there is nothing to retrieve. You've not provided enough information about your database (what RDBMS you're using, for instance) to enable us to help. TMyQuery is a generic SQL query component, so it doesn't provide any details either. Please [edit] to be more specific about your situation.

@JohnJohn Related: Get the new record primary key ID from MySQL insert query? This is also described in MySQL's own documentation: 3.6.11 Obtaining the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row Now, how you do this with TMyQuery, I don't know offhand without reviewing its source code to see how it interacts with MySQL behind the scenes.
